# Google drive API: can't upload files to the root folder using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using google drive API to upload files.
It works if I specify the id of subfolders. But when I pass the id of the root folder, the files are not uploaded.
Here is my request:

```
      drive.files.create(
    {
      auth: this.ggToken,
      fields: 'id',
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      media: {
        body: this.convertBufferToStream(file.buffer),
      },
      requestBody: {
        mimeType: file.mimetype,
        name: file.originalname,
        parents: ['root', '0AASRHiHHtzxrUk9PVA'],
      },
    },
    (e: Error, f: any) => {
      if (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
      console.log(f);
    },
  );
```

`0AASRHiHHtzxrUk9PVA` is the ID of the root folder (I get it by using drive.files.get API)
So what's wrong with my code? How can I upload files to the root folder?
Thanks.

**Update 1**
Here is my script:

```
      ggToken: JWT;

  constructor() {
    this.ggToken = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GG_DRIVE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      process.env.GG_DRIVE_PRIVATE_KEY,
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
      null,
    );
  }

  async uploadFiles(file: any) {
    const credentials = await this.ggToken.authorize();
    this.ggToken.setCredentials(credentials);
    const uploadedFile = await drive.files.create({
      auth: this.ggToken,
      fields:
        'id, name, mimeType, webViewLink, webContentLink, iconLink, size, originalFilename',
      media: {
        body: this.convertBufferToStream(file.buffer),
      },
      requestBody: {
        mimeType: file.mimetype,
        name: file.originalname,
        parents: ['root'],
        properties: {},
      },
    });
    return {
      driveResource: uploadedFile.data,
    };
  }
```

I got process.env.GG_DRIVE_CLIENT_EMAIL and       process.env.GG_DRIVE_PRIVATE_KEY from the json file after creating server account key.

Comment: If you want to upload the file to the root folder, I think that your script works. As other method, for example, how about removing the property of `parents` from `requestBody`? It's `requestBody: {mimeType: file.mimetype, name: file.originalname}`. Even if this modification didn't resolve your issue, please confirm the permissions for the root folder.

Comment: @Tanaike Removing `parents` doesn't work. I will check the permission of the root folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the file can be put to the root folder, I think that both your script and the modified script work. By the way, I cannot understand about the situation of `doesn't work`. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: From google drive api document: `If parents is not specified as part of a create request, the file will be placed directly in the user's My Drive folder`, so I remove `parents` fields, but the files are not uploaded to My Drive folder => it doesn't work :D And I don't know how to change the permission of My Drive.

Comment: It seems like I can't share the root folder. Google drive shows an error: `Sorry, an internal error has occurred and your request was not completed.`

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you upload the file in your own Google Drive, I think that you can do it without modifying the permissions. And also I think that your script works fine. So I think that you might try to upload the file to the Google Drive which is not yours. Because `supportsAllDrives: true` is used. How about this?

Comment: It's my Google Drive. I just try to add `supportsAllDrives: true` to solve my problem, it didn't work :D.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, can you manually upload a file to the root folder?

Comment: Of course, I can do it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. As the next step, can you provide your whole script? I would like to confirm your situation. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thank for your help, I just update my script.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the script. I could understand about the reason of your issue. The service account is different from your own account. So the Google Drive of service account is different from that of your account. By this, when a file is uploaded to the root folder using your script, the file is uploaded to the root folder of the Drive of service account. By this, the file cannot be seen at the drive of your account. If you want to upload the file to the root folder of the Drive of your account, please use OAuth2. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I got it. I will try to use OAuth2 and let you know the result. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you have any questions, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :D.

Comment: Thank you. That's good idea. I just add my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @Tanaike very much.
Here is his answer:

> Thank you for replying and adding the script. I could understand about the reason of your issue. The service account is different from your own account. So the Google Drive of service account is different from that of your account. By this, when a file is uploaded to the root folder using your script, the file is uploaded to the root folder of the Drive of service account. By this, the file cannot be seen at the drive of your account. If you want to upload the file to the root folder of the Drive of your account, please use OAuth2

With Oauth2, I can upload files to the root folder.
Here is my code:

```
      oauth2Client: OAuth2Client;

  constructor() {
    this.oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirectUri: 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground',
    });
    this.oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      access_token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
      refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    });
  }

  async uploadFiles(file: any) {
    const uploadedFile = await drive.files.create({
      auth: this.oauth2Client,
      fields:
        'id, name, mimeType, webViewLink, webContentLink, iconLink, size, originalFilename',
      media: {
        body: this.convertBufferToStream(file.buffer),
      },
      requestBody: {
        mimeType: file.mimetype,
        name: file.originalname,
        parents: ['root'],
      },
    });
    return {
      driveResource: uploadedFile.data,
    };
  }
```